# Is it safe to edit cshtml files on Umbraco?

Tags: razor, umbraco

I have to do some minor modifications on a website built with Umbraco and I'd like to know if it's safe to manually edit cshtml files?
I just need to edit html code & some variable's content.

In case of problem, is putting back the previous version of the cshtml file on the server enough or does it need other actions?

I'm a php dev I'm not familiar with .net at all. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can edit the cshtml files directly and outside of the Umbraco backend using a text editor of your choice. In fact, this is *my* preferred method. I typically edit cshtml files within Visual Studio so I can get the benefit of syntax highlighting and some auto-completion.